# Why is my CV 145% complete?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

On Careers, when filling out my CV, it is listed as being 145% complete.  Could someone tell me why this is?

Comment: Just guess, because I haven't played with it much yet, but I'm guessing it double-counts multiple experience entries or similar.

Comment: Its a feature :D

Comment: It's an obvious easter egg.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The over 100% is intentional -- just indicates that you've gone the "extra mile" beyond the minimum required.

[http://www.merryswankster.com/images/SpinalTap_Eleven-thumb.jpg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeOXsA8sp_E)

Comment: A ha! Good to know.

Comment: I'm not feelin' it.

Comment: Just wait until you get to 900% complete.

Comment: Gah. If I were to use C.SO, I wouldn't rest until I was over 9000% complete.

Comment: @Thomas Owens - WHAT, 9000?! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBtpyeLxVkI - that never gets old to me.

Comment: How complete is Jon Skeet's CV ?

Comment: Jon Skeet's CV is always ∞ % complete (aw, the infinity symbol is too darn small..)

Comment: To most common users this "feature" looks like a bug.  Be prepared for hundreds of bug report filings.

Comment: I also agree that a value greater than 100% is confusing. It doesn't really provide any useful information and, given the explanation, seems to be arbitrary and unimportant.

Comment: This seems likes a feature that Michael Scott would propose, if Dunder Mifflin was a software company.

Comment: I almost filed a bug report. This should be fixed.

Comment: In this case, I strongly disagree. There are still parts of my profile that are missing (my Personal Statement, for instance). Before, I would be notified and reminded of that (and possibly newer fields that have since been added). Now, just because I have a bunch of GitHub projects, those other fields don't count? It's just weird and unexpected. Maybe you can do this over-100% thing _when 100% of the fields have been filled in_, but **I don't think you should allow missing fields to be compensated for by overly-filled-in fields**.

Answer (score 6):

145% means that you're 45% better than the average programmer.  Congratulations.

Comment: omg,  I see metric-haters coming...

Comment: 100% is average - damn the curve in this class is tough.

Answer (score 5):

I'm reminded of this fictional exchange...

> STAN: **I need to talk about your
>   flair.**
>
> JOANNA: **Really? I have 15 buttons
>   on.**
>
> STAN: **Well, ok, 15 is minimum, ok?**
>
> STAN: **Now, it’s up to you whether or
>   not you want to just do the bare
>   minimum. Well, like Brian, for
>   example, has 37 pieces of flair.**
>
> JOANNA: **Ok. Ok, you want me to wear
>   more?**
>
> STAN: **Look, we want you to express
>   yourself, ok? If you think the bare
>   minimum is enough, then ok. *But some
>   people choose to wear more and we
>   encourage that, ok?* You do want to
>   express yourself, don't you?**

Though, true confession, when I got to over 100% on my CV I was pretty happy. :-)

Comment: You mean from **Office Space.** That wasn't fiction, it was true-life.

Comment: You know, the Nazis had pieces of flair that they made the Jews wear.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same way I scored 104% of possible points in a compilers class - extra credit.  Make sure your typing is neat and read the assignment thoroughly.

Comment: I was once scaled up to 112% in a mathematics test.

Comment: I once scored e in a maths test, which I felt was a little irrational.

Comment: You feel e was irrational? I'll meditate on that.