# What does "this one goes to 11" in completion status in edit cv mean

Tags: support, jobs

When I edit my CV on careers my completion status says "135% complete (this one goes to 11)". What does that mean?

[alt text http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/9382/editcv.png](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/9382/editcv.png)

Comment: See this link, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/why-is-my-cv-145-complete

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's a reference to Marshall amplifiers that go up to 11 instead of 10 (Get it? They're one louder!). The movie This is Spinal Tap [has a bit on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven).

Comment: Marshall implemented the "one more louder" Gain knob on some models as a tribute to Tap, if I recall correctly...

Answer (score 4):

As well as being a reference to This is Spinal Tap, it also means that because if you fill out more than 100% of the form.

With your details, one employer and one education section fully you'll have completed 100% of the form. Therefore, as you'll probably have several employers and education sections you can fill out the form to over 100%, as you have already done.

Answer (score 2):

I added in a direct link to the YouTube video in the UI.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeOXsA8sp_E

> The numbers all go **eleven**. Right across the board. Eleven ... eleven ... eleven ...
>
> Well, it's one louder, isn't it?