# My Careers 2.0 profile is 305% complete

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does “this one goes to 11” in completion status in edit cv mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27601/what-does-this-one-goes-to-11-in-completion-status-in-edit-cv-mean)
>   [Why is my CV 145% complete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/why-is-my-cv-145-complete)

While I'm happy to over-achieve, this sounds like a bug :)

Repro: I've created my profile from an invitation link. I've started adding my experience by hand, then noticed the 'import from LinkedIn' button. After importing some of my XP from LinkedIn, I got this completion rate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "this one goes to 11" in completion status in edit cv mean](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27601/what-does-this-one-goes-to-11-in-completion-status-in-edit-cv-mean), or, more accurately, [Why is my CV 145% complete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/why-is-my-cv-145-complete)

Comment: Ah, I looked up other questions, didn't find the second one, guess it wasn't tagged properly...