# How complete is your CV?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Just curious what types of scores Careers is giving to everyone / how much people are putting into their CV.

I'm at 115%. What about you?

Comment: See this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/why-is-my-cv-145-complete/24971#24971

Comment: Are you asking why its 115% or just asking a "wiki" question?

Comment: It's a poll.  Should be closed.  To satisfy curiosity, I'm at 195% complete, and you can see my CV here: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/adamdavis  There's nothing hidden, so maybe you can shed some light on how it's calculated by comparing your 115% CV with my 195% CV.

Comment: I'm at 260%. I can't seem to think of that as actually better.

Comment: Mine is 165% even though I've intentionally left some older stuff off it, which technically makes it 165% incomplete.

Comment: Mine is at 180%.  I am wondering what is 100% and how you get over?

Answer (score 1):

I'm at 255% but still 6 to 8 weeks till it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

[Mine](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/robertkoritnik) is at **370% complete**.