# Why is there no "not a real question" close option on MSO?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

MSO doesn't have the "not a real question" option when you vote to close. Is there a reason for this? Can we add this?

For reference - I wanted to use this reason to close [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33702/adblock-plus-blocking-so-ads-and-bad-practice-from-so-on-showing-same-ad-multiple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That question is, sadly, completely allowed.. it's discussion of and about the trilogy sites. Utterly on topic.

Doesn't mean it's a *good* question, of course.

The only truly off topic stuff here is when the question does not relate to the trilogy or Stack Overflow codebase in any way. (That's the one argument about doing DocType support here on meta that I belatedly came to realize was absolutely right.)

Comment: I felt the question wasn't a discussion but just a statement (rant). Oh well, at least we can downvote this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

MSO was launched, in part at least, to replace several unofficial forum / chat services started by SO users with an official place to discuss SO matters.

So unlike SO (and SF, and SU...), MSO actually allows "questions" that aren't really questions. [Discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [GTKY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29479/how-complete-is-your-cv) threads, [rants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/i-am-sick-of-downvoters)... they're all allowed. Except [when they're not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/)...

...Oh yeah - the moderation here on MSO is totally batshit fucking insane. Possibly because of the confusion surrounding the types of posts allowed, possibly because of the weird mix of moderator backgrounds, possibly due to some other cause. My money's on some weird emergent behavior involving four-cornered trilogies, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Understood - but I didn't think rants were welcome. Or maybe they are. If they are...