# How do I get my Careers Profile to 100 percent?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I've spent an unreasonably long time today filling in your form -- which, by the way, is sometimes a little ridiculous, like expecting 400 characters to describe being a freelance features writer. I've not got every little thing filled out, there are no more hints of what I should still do -- and my completion is at 95 percent.

I know gamification is a big thing, but honest, if I wanted to do a puzzle I'd find a sudoku book.

Please give me a hint what's missing?

Comment: I think you will have to fill out the as many fields as possible... I know you are aiming for 100% but look at [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/why-is-my-cv-145-complete)

Comment: If I could find another field to fill out, I would. That's the point/

Comment: I guess it's not co-related to filling out 100% fields then... That's tricky... I wish it could tell exactly what section needs completion... I guess one has to keep tweaking profile... adding more to Education, Experience but then again one has to have that more than what's already added... you have got my +1.

Comment: Okay, I got to 100 percent eventually, and still couldn't get it unlocked.  I finally hacked around until it unlocked. I think this actually should be reframed from a question into a bug report.

Comment: You can post an answer for your findings if they are different from what user 'Konamiman' said in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was in a similar situation and finally achieved 100% after following all the suggestions that appear in the right pane and expanding the "Responsibilities" section of my work experiences. If you want to take a look to get an idea of how much is required, [here it is](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/konamiman).